# MySQL Query not giving expected result

Tags: mysql

In my XAMPP server's database, table named report exist which consist several column with there fixed set of values (Ok, Not Ok, Done, Not Done, Not Available). For some column like, column 'battery' , when I fire query in XAMPP sql as "SELECT * FROM Report WHERE battery='yes'"; it returns 0 set of result(no records) even when there are several records in which battery value is 'yes'. It's also not working for selecting value 'no';
I think my query is correct but the output is wrong. Please help with solution for this. Also I am not making any spelling mistake related to database, table and column name.

```
SELECT * FROM report WHERE battery='yes';
SELECT * FROM report WHERE battery='no';

output : MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0044 seconds.)
```

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT DISTINCT battery FROM report`? Look at the exact values with spaces and exact case.

Comment: Show us the table creation statement and some rows of data.

Comment: Also `SELECT * FROM report WHERE battery != 'yes';` return any data?

Comment: Maybe there are extra spaces in the values, like `' yes'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't given enough information for us to help you very well. Please read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then please [edit] your question.